# How to use THIS keyword for functions that don't have an action in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many elements in a table which have variable widths, specified as such by their respective parents' data-attribute: percent="10" or percent="20", etc. How can i set each element's width dependent of their individual parent's data-attribute?

To make it clear here's my code:

HTML

```
<td percent="10"><div class="bar"></div></td>
<td percent="20"><div class="bar"></div></td>
<td percent="30"><div class="bar"></div></td>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.bar').css('width', $(this).parent().attr('percent')+'%');
```

Of course $(this) keyword doesn't work here, because its not defined inside an event.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function argument to execute the code for each element.

```
$('.bar').css('width', function() {
    return $(this).parent().attr('percent')+'%';
});
```

BTW, you shouldn't create nonstandard attributes. If you need custom data, use data attributes:

```
<td data-percent="10"><div class="bar"></div></td>
<td data-percent="20"><div class="bar"></div></td>
<td data-percent="30"><div class="bar"></div></td>
```

and then use `$(this).parent().data("percent")`

Comment: Ok thanks. WHat's wrong with creating non standard attributes?

Comment: You might conflict with future standard attributes.